# Adding Gridview new row on client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a TextBox and Button in the Parent GridView(gvTopic). If button is clicked I want to show newly added comment on client side in the Child GridView(gvComment) as well as storing data on database(may be background processing, similar to comment feature of this website).

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTopic" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gvComment" runat="server">
            <%--Comments--%>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

right now, I'm binding child GridView (gvComment) on the Button click which saves data in database first and then binds it, so long process to showing newly added comment.

or is there any alternate solution for this?

Comment: u mean Master/Detail implementation ?  then http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14861/Multilevel-Nested-Master-Detail-Data-Display-Using

Answer (score 0):

I don't think GridView provides client side row adding , some other grids like Telerik's RadGrid provide this feature.

However you can combination of javascript and hidden fields to achieve this.

Use javascript to dynamically create a copy of exist TR node , appened node at the last of TABLE , replace the inner node TD values and store these values to hidden field in preferly JSON format.

Comment: thanks for reply. can you provide any example as a reference.